# Opening an External SWF file using openWithDefaultApplication()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i'm trying to open an external SWF file using openWithDefaultApplication(), i did the following:

```
openButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openSwfFile);
function openSwfFile(e:MouseEvent){
    var sourceFile:File =  File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("swfFile.swf");
    var destination:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("swfFile.swf");

    //copying the swfFile to the Documents directory:
    sourceFile.copyTo(destination, true);

    //opening the swfFile:
    destination.openWithDefaultApplication();   
    }
```

(i copied the file to the windows "Documents" directory because openWithDefaultApplication() doesn't open a file in the application directory.) This works fine when i compile (hit Ctrl+Enter), when i click the openButton, the swf file is opened and everything is fine. but when i open the app swf file separately and click the openButton, the app swf file closes immediately without throwing any error, why is that?

Comment: Do you open it like any other SWF, with Standalone Flash Player, installed on your system?

Comment: yes i do, i compiled the whole app in a .exe format and it worked fine, why is that?

Comment: Do you understand the concept of runtime? Specifically AIR runtime vs Flash Player runtime?

Comment: No, can you please clarify?

Comment: Simply, a standard that defines what kind of API the SWF application has access to. **File** class is an AIR runtime only class because it provides you with unrestricted read/write access to local storage, which would be unsafe if available in browser, for example. Standalone Flash Player that is associated with running SWF files is restricted to Flash Player runtime for the same reason. That's why it doesn't provide the application with the **File** class and crashes upon trying to use it.